# Javascript, SOAP, Execute, Variable and function call

Tags: javascript, function, variables, soap

Is this

```
var result = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Execute(setStateRequest);
```

1. just storing the function into the variable,
2. executing and storing the return value into the variable,
3. or doing both?

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find something useful in the internet. Looking at http://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Soap%20Functions
it looks like the function is executed but i am not sure.

I also tested it with a normal Javascript inside the chrome browser and got this result:

```
> function test(a){
      console.log(a);
  };
undefined
```

Calling the function normal

```
> test("asd");
asd
```

With a variable declaration

```
> var x = test("asd");
asd
```

But it looks like the variable does not contain any information

```
> console.log(x);
undefined
> x
undefined
```

Now I am completely confused. Why is the function called as variable when it is never stored? I am new to Javascript and need to understand what this is exactly doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is storing the return value of the function into a variable.

The reason your test function is not working is because you don't return a value in test.

```
function test(num) {
  return num * 2;
}
var doubled = test(2);
// doubled now contains 4
var doubleVariable = test;
// doubleVariable is now the same as test
doubleVariable(2)
// returns 4
```

This [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) may clarify things a bit more

Comment: Oh that was my bad. Thanks for your help. :)